# Authentication in mongodb 3.0.1 using credentials

Tags: java, mongodb

How to create credentials and clients for authenticating mongodb database

```
  MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(
            "usernmae", "database", "password".toCharArray());
```

This creates crendentials how to validate across the created username and password

Comment: Can you pls more specific

Comment: @PSM  I have a database created in mongodb .It mus be authenticated before it accessed. So how to protect database with username and password. how can i do this explain me breifly

Comment: By coading or in mongoDb ?

Answer (score 0):

For now you can only define if the user has read only or write permissions on a database. So basically the only thing mongodb cares is if you typed the right password for the right user.

Personally in all production environment I would recommend to use the secure mode, because even if you allow only connection from a localhost any users who has access to the local server or any malicious script on the host can easily wipe all your data.